# What does "&" indicate in "&:hover" using SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass

```css
&:hover {
    .line-1,
    .line-2, 
    .line-3 {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
  }

  &.active {

    .line-1,
    .line-2, 
    .line-3 {
      background-color: #fff;
    }


    .line-1 {
      animation: animate-line-1 .7s $cubic-bezier-in forwards;
    }
    .line-2 {
      animation: animate-line-2 .7s $cubic-bezier-in forwards;
    }
    .line-3 {
      animation: animate-line-3 .7s $cubic-bezier-in forwards;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's the [parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) in Sass.

Answer (score 1):

`&:hover` means "when this element is hovered then style it".

For example:

```css
.button {
    background: red;

    &:hover {
        background: green;
    }
}
```

This means: the default background color of the button is red but when you hover it, the background changes to green.

This code is the equivalent of:

```css
.button {
    background: red;
}

.button:hover {
    background: green;
}
```

The code above is written using "SASS", a new way to write CSS. You can found more about it here:
[Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax).